# How to check how many same characters/digits are there in a c++ string?

Tags: c++, string, find

Does anybody know how to check how much same characters/digits are there in a string?
By my understanding std::find only checks if there is a specific character in a string and only returns true or false. In my situation I need to find how much times is a specific character/digit in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check following functions `std::count` and `std::count_if`. As for your problem code below should do the trick - print out the number of occurrences of 3.

```
int a[] = { 3, 1, 3, 2, 1 }; 
int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); 
std::cout << std::count(a, a + n, 3);
```